# Convert SQL computer to ROLL UP sql server 2012 since its no longer support compute

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, rollup

I have db like this:

For meaning:
LOP: class
SINHVIEN: student
KHOA: department
MONHOC: subject
DIEMTHI: mark

I want to do the query to list ALL the CLASS and the number of CLASS belong to each DEPARTMENT

```
SELECT khoa.makhoa,tenkhoa,malop,tenlop FROM khoa,lop 
WHERE khoa.makhoa=lop.makhoa 
ORDER BY khoa.makhoa 
COMPUTE COUNT(malop) BY khoa.makhoa
```

[image]

and the result look like
[image]

But, the SQL 2012 NO LONGER support COMPUTE, they said it's can be done with ROLL UP but I can't do with its syntax, please help me

Update 1:
RADAR's result, with more help
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can replace `COMPUTE` with `ROLLUP` and GROUP BY

```
SELECT khoa.makhoa,tenkhoa,malop,tenlop , COUNT(malop) FROM khoa,lop 
WHERE khoa.makhoa=lop.makhoa 
GROUP BY khoa.makhoa,tenkhoa,malop,tenlop
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: I run it, and the result have many NULL cell, and count column cover many "1", it doesn't seem like the result which I am looking :)

Comment: If you need to match to a recordset, post the actual recordset, not a report.